# How can I make bar charts symmetrical in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

I have a horizontal bar with two datasets to show a simple age pyramide.

I'm using negative values for `female` and positive values for `male`

[image]

How do I make the bars from both datasets symmetrical and remove spacing between them?
This is the code.

```
<script>

  new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart"), {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: ["18-25", "25-30", "30-35", "35-40"],
        datasets: [
        {
            data: <?php echo json_encode($data_chartm); ?>,
            label: "Male",
            backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
        },
        {
            data: <?php echo json_encode($data_chartf); ?>,
            label: "Female",
            backgroundColor: ["blue", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"]
        }

          ]
    },
    options: {
            title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Pyramide des ages'
        },

    }
});
</script>
```

This is the content of $data_chartm and $data_chatf:

```
$data_chartm=[4,5,9,10];

$data_chartf=[-4,-5,-9,-10];
```

Answer (score 0):

Baha, é só colocar a propriedade scales stacked true

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("ProdFicha_Idade"), {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: ["18-25", "25-30", "30-35", "35-40"],
        datasets: [
        {
            data: [1,2,3,4],
            label: "Male",
            backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
        },
        {
            data: [-1,-2,-3,-4],
            label: "Female",
            backgroundColor: ["blue", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"]
        }

            ]
    },
    options: {
            title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Pyramide des ages'
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true
            }]
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Could you please write the answer only in English. Thanks.